# textbox to dropdown and remove content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a couple of codes to get content from textboxes and put them in a dropdown boxes, i have a 5 page form using  and javascript to switch between pages with a onclick functoin, on step 3 i have 9 texboxes where names are being inputed once i click on next, i have a copy function which will copy the names in the 9 textbox and put then in one dropdown boxe, but when i click on back where i go back to step 3, and click next, the content on the dropdown box is duplicated how can i correct my code so that when i click on back, i have a function that erase the old content on the dropdown box codes are below; i also attached a screenshot of what is happening when you click back.

this is for the function to copy the textbox content to the dropdown boxes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function data_copy()
{
    if(document.forms[0].health1.value == ""){
        var select = document.getElementById("health1");
        var value = "";
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName1.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName2.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName3.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName4.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName5.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName6.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName7.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName8.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
        var value = document.form1.passName9.value;
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
    }else{
        document.form1.pass1Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass2Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass3Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass4Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass5Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass6Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass7Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass8Name.value="";
        document.form1.pass9Name.value="";
    }
}
</script>
```

the call action code to copy the items on drop down box

```
<a href="#" onclick="data_copy(); "><img src="images/step4.jpg" border="0" width="30%" />
```

this is the back function where i need to erase the old content of the drop down because they are duplicating

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function data_nocopy()
{
    if(document.forms[0].health1.value > 0){
        var select = document.getElementById("health1");
        var value = "";
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(value, value);
    }
}
</script>
```

the call function to erase but not working

```
![<a href="#" onclick="data_nocopy(); "><img src="images/step4.jpg" border="0" width="30%" />][1]
```

thanks a lot hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to clear dropdownlist items. Sample code is given below

**In Jquery** :

```
$('#health1')[0].options.length = 0;
```

**In Javascript** :

```
document.getElementById("health1").options.length = 0;
```